# ( countability axiom )Let $\tau$ and $\sigma$ be topologies over a set $X$ such that $\tau \subseteq \sigma$...

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, lindelof-spaces

> Let $\tau$ and $\sigma$ be topologies over a set $X$ such that $\tau \subseteq \sigma$.

> a) If $(X, \tau )$ satisfies a certain countability axiom then $(X, \sigma)$ also
> satisfy?

> b) If $(X, \sigma)$ satisfies a certain countability axiom then $(X, \tau )$ also
> satisfy?

1.First-Countable

A topological space $T=(S,\tau)$ satisfies the First Axiom of Countability if and only if every point in $S$ has a countable local basis.

2.Second-Countable

A topological space $T=(S,\tau)$ satisfies the Second Axiom of Countability if and only if its topology has a countable basis.

3.Separable

A topological space $T=(S,\tau)$ is separable if and only if there exists a countable subset of S which is everywhere dense in $T$.

4.Lindelöf

A topological space $T=(S,\tau)$ is a Lindelöf if and only if every open cover of S
has a countable subcover.

As 1,2,3 and 4 depend on countable sets, we can guarantee that if $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ and $\sigma$ is countable then $\tau$ is countable. But if $\tau $ is countable, nothing can be said of $\sigma$ so a) it can't be true, right?

b) 1.
By the definition of first-countable, every point in $\sigma$ has a countable local basis in $T$.

So the intersection of $\tau$ with the countable local basis of $\sigma$ give us a countable local basis for $\tau$.But every point in $\tau$ is also a point in $\sigma$, so $\tau$ is also first countable.

2.
By the definition of second-countable $\sigma$ has a countable basis.So, $\exists \cal{B} \subseteq \sigma$ $ then for all $U \in \sigma$, $U$ is a union of sets from $\cal{B}$.But
\cal{B} is countable. As $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ it follows that a $\sigma$ itself is a union of sets from $\cal{B}$.So $\tau$ is also second countable.

3.
Let $\mathbb R_7$, which is both separable ({7} is dense)
Let $Y = \mathbb R$ \ {$7$} $\subseteq \mathbb R_7$. This space is  not separable.

4.
Let X be the space of all uncountable ordinals, together with the first uncountable
ordinal itself,so the space $\sigma + 1$ is Lindelöf, but the subspace
$\tau = \sigma + 1 - 1$ is not.

How is my answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding first countability: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a non-first-countable space. Let $\tau_0=\{\varnothing,X\}$ and let $\tau_1$ be the discrete topology on $X$. Then $\tau_0$ and $\tau_1$ are both first-countable topologies, and $\tau_0\subseteq\tau\subseteq\tau_1$.

Comment: Your above claim is false: there are topologies on a countable set, which are not first countable. But, of course,  the discrete topology on a countable set is first and second countable. Hence, these properties are not preserved by weaker topologies.